Is it Husn Khatima?
Assalmu Alaykum,
We live in a very lonely europe country in the middle of mountains and christians or atheists.
My father he was so full of sabr (patience) and he always prayed, also always said "If you die here no one is gonna get to know it".
27 April he died but in a city full of muslims, he was VERY ill (dyalisis patient, pacemaker, diabetic, blood pressure), but he never died by any those illnesses, he died by gastric and abdominal inflammation that made his heart exhausted and made him have a heart attack, he was in company of my mother, but at some point he just called her "I am falling" and died without pain (alhamdulillah) and foam came out from his esophage as he did have fluid on his lungs. So he was foaming after it turned pink due to the blood. My mother said the shahada many times to him while being scared and shocked.
Also he will get to be burried on his country and in Jumu'a.
Now I see an indonesian article where he says it is "su al khatima"....made me cry and pray all day, he never said something bad and hundreds of people came to the place he was laying on the street to assist us because he always helped and said good words.
